# ruby 1.8.7 and web service

Tags: ruby, web-services

I'm new to Ruby and want to write a web service using Ruby. Some constraints are:

1. Ruby 1.8.7
2. Windows 2008 Server

I found that the Sinatra gem may help. I want to know if there are any other options beside Sinatra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sinatra is a very easy-to-use way to go, and what I'd recommend to get your feet wet.

There are other solutions:

- [Padrino](http://www.padrinorb.com) is built on-top of Sinatra, and offers additional functionality, but for your purposes Sinatra is still a more easily accessible way to go as you'll spend less time configuring.
- [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) is the heavy-weight solution for Ruby, but if you are just learning the language then I'd recommend Sinatra still. Rails is very powerful but a lot of things it does will seem like magic, though they are actually based on standard Ruby features. So, I think you are still better off learning Ruby and working with Sinatra to get the basics.

Comment: Rails? I thought it is for building websites not Web services? If it is, could you give me further details. Thanks. Pete

Comment: Rails can be used for all sorts of things. It doesn't have to build pages, it can receive incoming requests and return anything you tell it to. It's a MVC with a lot of nice tools and support code.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into Rails since it's quite popular.

Comment: It is, but learning it is a steep learning curve if you don't know Ruby to begin with. Sinatra, on the other hand, will make more sense.